# Haskell Parsing: x ++ y : z

Tags: parsing, haskell

In Haskell, why is `x ++ y : z` parsed as `x ++ (y : z)` and not as `(x ++ y) : z`?

For instance, `[1] ++ 2 : [3]` evaluates to `[1,2,3]`.

Both `(++)` and `(:)` are right-associative with precedence 5.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? Since they are right-associative with the same precedence, the expression is evaluated from the right and not from the left.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that they are ***right associative*** means that these are parsed "right-to-left" so to speak. It thus means that *x ⊕ y ⊕ z* is parsed as *x⊕ (y ⊕ z)*. So that means that `x ++ y : z` is indeed parsed as `x ++ (y : z)`.

There are good reasons to make both `(:)` and `(++)` right associative. For the "cons" `(:)` operator, it means that we can write `1 : 4 : 2 : []`, since it is parsed as `1 : (4 : (2: []))`, which is correct in terms of the types. If would parse it like `((1:4):2:[])`, then `1:4` would for example be wrong, since it expects an item as the first operand, and list of these items as the second operand. We can of course still let the Haskell parser parse it as a list, but that would result in a large amount of extra parenthesis.

For `(++)` it is better to parse it right-to-left as well due to performance reasons. `x ++ y` takes linear time in the size of `x`. So that means that if we parse `x ++ (y ++ z)`, it will take *|x| + |y|* steps. If we would parse this as `(x ++ y) ++ z`, it would take *2×|x|+|y|*, since the first time we apply `(x ++ y)` it runs in the size of `x`, but then `(x ++ y) ++ z` runs in the size of `x ++ y`. This thus would mean that if we concatenate *n* lists each with a size of *m*, it will not run in *O(n×m)*, but in *O(n<sup>2</sup>×m)*.

Comment: The fact that wasn't clear to me - and that's also not entirely obvious from your answer - is that associativity in Haskell is used not only to disambiguate expressions of the form x⊕y⊕z but also to disambiguate expressions of the form x⊕y⊗z when ⊕ and ⊗ have **the same precedence and the same associativity.** To quote the Haskell 2010 report: "Consecutive unparenthesized operators with the same precedence must both be either left or right associative to
avoid a syntax error."

Comment: @user188895: yes indeed, given the same precedence, it means these are parsed right-to-left (also with "mixed" operators, as you show in the comment). Note that the associativity of the operators must be the same, as is noted in the Haskell report: "*Consecutive unparenthesized operators with the same precedence must both be either left or right associative to avoid a syntax error.*" (chapter 3).